# OL3 How to select features of a WMS layer

Tags: openlayers, ows

I want to show on the map the features of the saved layers from a GeoServer server, but I don't know how to do this...

Like this, but with the dragbox interaction...

I have this code:

```
var select = new ol.interaction.Select();
mapa.addInteraction(select);
var selectedFeatures = select.getFeatures();
var dragBox = new ol.interaction.DragBox({
        condition: ol.events.condition.always,
        style: new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: [0, 0, 255, 1]
            })
        })
    });

    mapa.addInteraction(dragBox);

    dragBox.on('boxend', function(e) {
        if (capaActiva != null) {
            var info = [];
            var extent = dragBox.getGeometry().getExtent();
            var source = capaActiva.getSource();
            console.log(source);
            var url = source.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(extent, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',{'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/plain'});
            console.log(url);

        } else {
            Ext.MessageBox.show({
                title: 'Error',
                msg: 'Check a layer',
                buttonText: {                        
                    ok: 'Aceptar',
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: in general you can't select a WMS layer as it is a picture of your map data.

Comment: More precisely, you can't give an extent to `getGetFeatureUrl`, as it can only query the server with a single pair of coordinates (that's how getFeatureInfo works in a WMS server).

Comment: Ok got it, but how can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

WMS GetFeatureInfo only supports queries with one pair of coordinates at a time. Therefore, you can't use an extent to request feature information from a WMS server. You can however use WFS to load the vector data directly into the application, or use a click type interaction (`ol.interaction.Pointer` for example).

If you are using GeoServer, the request also lacks some required parameters. If only one pair of coordinates are passed to the function, it would return an error from the server side, as no `QUERY_LAYERS` options are set. The correct function would look like the following:

```
var source = capaActiva.getSource();
var viewResolution = map.getView().getResolution();
console.log(source);
var queryLayers = source.getParams().layers;
var url = source.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(coords, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',{'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/plain', 'QUERY_LAYERS': queryLayers});
console.log(url);
```

With the URL, you can send an `XMLHttpRequest` to the server, and process the response, if the request was successful.